# Why does Postgrex - Ecto throw this not_null_violation error?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto, postgrex

## Error

Here's the error that I encountered when I'm testing my Account changeset. It seems like it would only be caused by the Ecto migration with wrongly structured database, but the `ecto.migrate` runs fine, as also Postgresql doesn't throw any error when I'm trying to insert a row using a similar changeset below.

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 23502 (not_null_violation): null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint

     table: accounts
     column: email

 Failing row contains (118, 66168645856, 1, 2018-08-17 03:19:12.176247, 2018-08-17 03:19:12.17626, null, null, null, null).
 code: account = insert(:account)
 stacktrace:
   (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:554: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.struct/8
   (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:547: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
   (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:213: anonymous fn/14 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
   (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:125: Ecto.Repo.Schema.insert!/4
   test/schema/account_test.exs:26: (test)
```

## Ecto migrations

> migration_create_account.ex

```
def change do
    create table(:accounts) do
        add :phone_number, :string
        add :access_level, :integer

        timestamps()
    end
end
```

> migration_add_account.ex

```
def change do
    alter table(:accounts) do
        add :email, :string
        add :auth_token, :string
        add :auth_token_expires_at, :utc_datetime
        add :signed_in_at, :utc_datetime
    end

    create unique_index(:accounts, :email, where: "email IS NOT NULL")
    create unique_index(:accounts, [:phone_number], where: "phone_number IS NOT NULL")
end
```

## ExMachina

> factory.ex

```
def account_factory do
    random_mobile_number = Enum.map(0..10, fn _i -> :rand.uniform(9) end)
    |> List.foldl("", fn i, acc -> acc <> "#{i}" end)

    %Account{
      phone_number: random_mobile_number,
      access_level: 1
    }
end
```

## ExUnit

> account_test.exs

```
describe "Account.changeset/2" do
   test "should check for valid phone number" do
     account          = insert(:account)
     negative_number  = %{phone_number: "-123233239" }
     refute changeset(account, negative_number).valid?
   end
end
```

## Ecto schema and changeset

```
schema "accounts" do
    field :email       , :string
    field :phone_number, :string
    field :access_level     , :integer
    field :access_level_text, :string, virtual: true
    field :auth_token           , :string
    field :auth_token_expires_at, :naive_datetime
    field :signed_in_at         , :naive_datetime

    timestamps()
end

@required_params ~w(phone_number email access_level access_level_text)
def changeset(account, attrs) do
  account
  |> cast(attrs, @required_params)
  |> cast_access_level_text()
  |> validate_required([:access_level])
  |> validate_required_contact_handle()
  |> validate_number(:access_level, less_than: 3, greater_than: 0)
  |> validate_subset(:access_level_text, @access_levels)
  |> validate_format(:email, @email_regex)
  |> validate_format(:phone_number, @phone_number_regex)
  |> unique_constraint(:phone_number)
end
```

Comment: Exceptions in Elixir are _raised_, not _thrown_ in the first place. Try to avoid this confusion, since Elixir has also [`Kernel.throw/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#throw/1) for non-local returns. Now the main question is: **Ecto raises when you try to do exactly what?**

Comment: Your `account_factory` is missing email. You defined `email IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @TheAnh that’s not correct, `email` is defined as nullable.

Comment: Try using a list instead of the `:email` atom by itself: `unique_index(:accounts, [:email])`. I also don't think you need the where clause to exclude null values since postgres does not take null values into account with unique constraints.

Comment: You also need a `unique_constraint()` for the email field in your changeset.

Comment: Off topic: in your `factory.ex` file, you can do the following: `Enum.random(1_000_000_000..9_999_999_999) |> to_string()` to get a random phone number. Much cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. What happened in my case is that because I changed migrations after using `ecto.migrate`, so that the migration changes differs between the test database and development database.

I just ran `MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.reset` to sync database between the environments.